# Is it possible to initialize a Singleton from a specific method and not when application is executed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

Is it possible to initialize a Singleton from a specific method and not when application is executed?

I need to run a method in viewdidload depending if Singleton returns nil or not but as it has being created when the app runs, then it never returns nil.

Comment: i did not understand a thing

Comment: I don't know how you are implementing the singleton pattern but usually the object is initialised the first time you access it and not at the beginning of app execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getInstance() of a Singleton, by definition will never return `null`. If the Singleton instance is not created yet, then it will be created and the object reference will be returned. I guess the only time you will get `null` back is if the object creation failed for some reason (out of memory or some such unforeseen circumstances).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to understand. Thank you.

Comment: @Edu. Can you also please upvote. Some user has down voted it for no apparent reason :)

Comment: I would be happy to but I am new to StackOverflow and I need 5 more reputation points to be able to vote.:S

Comment: I see. Thx for trying anyways. Appreciate your update.